# How do we display generated class name in small letters in JSON Response

Tags: json, jackson

I have JSON schema as follows

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "required":false,
    "properties":{
        "example": {
            "type":"object",
            "required":false,
            "properties":{
                "age": {
                    "type":"number",
                    "required":false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is saved as ExampleResponse.jss . 
Using 'jsonschema2pojo' maven plugin, i generated POJO class from this schema. Using this class I am trying to create a JSON response and the expected output response should be

```
{
"example":{
 "age":68
}
}
```

Since the Generated POJO is

class Example { ..... }

output Response i am getting is

```
   {
"Example":{
 "age":68
}
}
```

How I can achieve desired response in which i have lower case 'example' word.

Comment: I think you're missing some details. Can you clarify your input and expected output? Also, try to fix your line breaks. Add two spaces to the end of a line if you want there to be a break before the next line. (Your "class Example..." isn't on a newline like you wanted it to be.)

Comment: Update question with input and expected output.